# Convert NSNumber to NSDecimalNumber

Tags: objective-c, init, nsnumber, nsdecimalnumber

I realize that NSDecimalNumber inherits from NSNumber.

However, I am struggling to figure out how I can init an NSDecimalNumber from an NSNumber or how to convert an NSNumber to an NSDecimalNumber.

I have tried

```
NSDecimalNumber* d = [aNumber copy];
```

where `aNumber` is an NSNumber object to no avail.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, `[NSNumber copy]` is never going to return a `NSDecimalNumber`… I’m only aware of conversions via `NSDecimal` (like in the answers below) or via `NSString`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can do:

```
NSDecimalNumber *decNum = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[aNumber decimalValue]];
```

Comment: Only problem is that passing an NSNumber with value of 2e+34 ends up with decNum of 2 and 34 zeros. would like it to maintain the same mantissa and exponent.

Comment: `2e+34` is 2 with 34 zeros. Those are the same number expressed in two different ways.

Answer (score 21):

So:

```
NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
NSDecimalNumber *d = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[number decimalValue]];
```

And in Swift

```
let number = NSNumber(int: 10)
let dec = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: number.decimalValue)
```

Comment: The 2nd one isn't valid (and in both cases `d` needs to be a pointer).

Comment: @rmaddy what are you talking about?

Comment: @Andy The answer has been edited twice (as of this comment) since my original comment. Look at the edit history to see what the answer looked like at the time of my comment.